# Can I prepare/ready a quickened spell?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

This is the scenario (still dnd 3.5): a lvl 15 wizard will cast a powerful spell on an enemy who is sure to close in melee to him. He's smart so he would like to Quicken Dimension Hop (lvl 2, so costing a lvl 6 slot) to get away from the enemy once the enemy closes in melee.

Is there any way to use the rules to prepare (or ready) the quickened spell in order to make the attacker's melee ability null?

The wizard is assumed to have already prepared the quickened Dimension hop in a lvl 6 slot.

It makes very much sense for smart characters to do such a thing, but the rules on how to achieve this seem to elude me.

Comment: Unless I'm reading this question wrong, it seems that both answers below missed the following point - the scenario is "On the same round, the wizard should: a) cast a powerful spell and b) setup the 'melee evasion trick'" - is that your intention? If yes, the wizard will use his standard action in that round for (a), so he can't use it to ready (b).

Comment: @G0BLiN  I asked--in a now-deleted comment--exactly that. The author confirmed that avoiding the attack was important and that casting the "powerful spell" comes later. I expect an edit will soon clarify that point.

Comment: @HeyICanChan So, the "powerful spell" is expected to dispatch the enemy? (or at least render his melee attack negligible / impossible) - otherwise the wizard will still face this problem after casting that spell...

Comment: @G0BLiN Yes, I think that's the plan: Get some breathing room *then* blaze away with the powerful spell, **not** get some breathing room *and* blaze away with the powerful spell.

Answer (score 3):

To nullify enemy's combat ability by teleporting, the teleport would have to be an **immediate action**. That means that it can be cast even outside your turn, once per round, but not on the same turn as a swift action.

> Much like a swift action, an immediate action consumes a very small amount of time, but represents a larger expenditure of effort and energy than a free action. However, unlike a swift action, an immediate action can be performed at any time — even if it's not your turn. Casting feather fall is an immediate action, since the spell can be cast at any time.

*(d20srd.org)*

There is a wizard variant, named **abrupt jaunt**(PHB2), that allows this (int times per day) in exchange for your familiar.

Please make sure that Abrupt Jaunt is okay with your group before you take it, it is considered overpowered by many.

Alternatively, you can choose to **ready a standard action** to teleport away, using any such spell you know, if you wish, but you lose your standard action for the turn.

> The ready action lets you prepare to take an action later, after your turn is over but before your next one has begun. Readying is a standard action. It does not provoke an attack of opportunity (though the action that you ready might do so).
>
> You can ready a standard action, a move action, or a free action. To do so, specify the action you will take and the conditions under which you will take it. Then, any time before your next action, you may take the readied action in response to that condition. The action occurs just before the action that triggers it. If the triggered action is part of another character’s activities, you interrupt the other character.

*(d20srd.org)*

Comment: i was hoping one could ready the quickened spell. perhaps through some obscure rules (TM). :)

Comment: You can ready the quickened spell, but readying it is still a standard action. You are better off just taking Abrupt Jaunt, if that's your intent.

Comment: Abrupt Jaunt is so good largely because it lets you do this so easily. Immediate action teleport is *amazing*.

Answer (score 2):

## Yes, A Foe's Attack Can Be Negated

*A vast number of battlefield conditions, class features, feats, special abilities, spells, and other things affect this scenario. This is deliberately the described scenario at its most basic.*

1. The caster takes the standard action [ready](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/specialInitiativeActions.htm#ready) and picks the action he'll take and picks the condition under which he'll takes the action; a reasonable action and condition is *I cast the spell* dimension hop *modified by feat Quicken Spell when a foe makes a melee attack against me.*

   - The DM determines if the action and the condition are appropriate.
   - The spell *dimension hop* needn't be modified by the feat Quicken Spell to do this. If it *is* so modified, though, casting the spell *dimension hop* doesn't provoke attacks of opportunity as casting a spell modified by the feat Quicken Spell (like any spell cast an immediate or swift action) doesn't provoke attacks of opportunity.
2. When the foe makes a melee attack against the caster, the caster's ready action triggers. The ready action occurs *before* the condition that triggers the ready action. Assuming the spell *dimension hop* transports the caster beyond the foe's reach, because the foe is incapable of continuing its action after the caster has completed his readied action the foe's action is wasted.
3. The caster's new place in the initiative order is immediately before the foe who triggered the caster's ready action.